# Change row group labels in gt table (with superscript/subscript and line breaks). Customising row group labels in R

Tags: r, subscript, superscript, gt

I have the following data and table:

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
a <- rnorm(21, mean = 112, sd =12)
colour <- rep(c("Blue", "Red", "Green"), 7)

data <- data.frame(colour, a) %>% 
  group_by(colour) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(a), sd = sd(a), n = n()) %>%
  mutate(grp = html("[H<sub>2</sub>O]")) %>% 
  rename(cat = colour)

b <- rnorm(21, mean = 60, sd =12)
day <- rep(c("2", "4", "6"), 7)

data2 <- data.frame(day, b) %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(a), sd = sd(a), n = n()) %>%
  mutate(grp = html("[H<sub>2</sub>O] Additition <br> (Days)")) %>% 
  rename(cat =  day)

bind_rows(data, data2) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  gt(rowname_col = "cat") 

bind_rows(data, data2) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  gt() %>%
  tab_options(row_group.as_column = TRUE)
```

The row group labels appear literally as '`[H<sub>2<\sub>O]`', rather than [H<sub>2</sub>O] etc. It is likely that I am using HTML wrong and it needs to be used with another package/function. I have also tried using `cols_label` but doesn't recognise these as columns in the dataframe.

Is there also a way to have the row groups column vertically centered, rather than at the top where is currently is? How do you bold these row groups?

Answer (score 1):

The `html` function won't work outside of a `gt` table, so you'll have to create the row groups using `tab_row_group` and add the html labels there.

```
data <- data.frame(colour, a) %>% 
  group_by(colour) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(a), sd = sd(a), n = n()) %>%
  mutate(grp = "color") %>% 
  rename(cat = colour)

data2 <- data.frame(day, b) %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(a), sd = sd(a), n = n()) %>%
  mutate(grp = "day") %>% 
  rename(cat =  day)

bind_rows(data, data2) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_row_group(
    label = html("[H<sub>2</sub>O]"),
    rows = grp == "color"
  ) %>% 
  tab_row_group(
    label = html("[H<sub>2</sub>O] Additition <br> (Days)"),
    rows = grp == "day"
  ) %>% 
  cols_hide(grp)
```